# Spring Boot @StepScope errors 'Cannot subclass final class java.lang.String'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

So I have a bean that requires some job parameters. And this bean returns a string. But because it needs job parameters I need to add `@StepScope` right. This is how my bean looks.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public String createInitialDownloadLinkForEntityMutation(@Value("#{jobParameters['link_date']}")String link_date,
                                                                   @Value("#{jobParameters['link_time']}")String link_time,
                                                                   @Value("#{jobParameters['link_id']}")String link_id){
   return "https://leidata-preview.gleif.org/storage/golden-copy-files/" +
            link_date.substring(0, 4) + "/" +
            link_date.substring(4, 6) + "/" +
            link_date.substring(6, 8) + "/" +
            link_id + "/" +
            link_date + "-" +
            link_time + "-" +
            "gleif-goldencopy-rr-golden-copy.csv.zip";
}
```

Now when I run the program I get an error that its conflicting with beans and stuff. But the true cause of that is that the bean is returning a string, or so I have read. Now I am lost as what to do with it. How would I make this work/fix it?

This is the full error:
https://hastebin.com/uretocecob.rb

Comment: By not making it a bean... I assume that this String is going to be injected somewhere, do the construction there.

Comment: @M.Deinum I thought it needed to be a bean for the job parameters, but I see what you mean. Ill try that